# Why can't the compiler ever elide the vtable?

Tags: c++

Sometimes I create an abstract class merely for implementation hiding, as an alternative to the pimpl idiom. If there is only one descendant and no public visibility outside the library that I'm building, why can't the linker remove the vtable?

I tried some experiments with clang and `-Os`. I added this to the constructor of one of my private impl classes:

```
printf("%p vs %p\n", this, &_first_member_field);
```

I *always* see an 8-byte difference between these two pointers, which I assume is the vtable pointer since I'm on a 64-bit arch. I also tried:

`-no-rtti -flto=full -fvirtual-function-elimination -fstrict-vtable-pointers`

But those 8 bytes never go away.  Is this due to spec compliance?

Comment: If the abstract class is only visible in the compilation unit, who is it hiding the implementation from?

Comment: It's not due to the C++ standard, but there may be some ABI or something responsible for it.  It could also be that this is such an edge case the optimizer just doesn't even look for it

Comment: Does the base class have `virtual` methods that the derived class overrides? If so, then the vtable can't really be eliminated, even if the classes are used in only 1 translation unit. And yes, the extra 8 bytes are likely the vtable pointer, if you are compiling for 64bit.

Comment: @NathanPierson I probably meant "library", not "compilation unit".  It's hiding the implementation from other files that do #include "myclass.h".

Comment: In a theoretical sense, a whole program optimizer can eliminate the vtables.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes in fact the base class consists solely of pure virtuals that the derived class overrides.  In a theoretical sense, I don't see why a whole program optimizer can't eliminate the vtables.

Comment: But you aren't actually checking for presence of the vtables in the resulting binary, you are checking whether the memory layout of the class reserved space for a pointer to the vtable.  Which is something else entirely and probably not something the optimizer is capable of changing.

Comment: @prideout vtables aren't mandated by the standard so the compiler can do what it likes just as long as the observable effect of the program is according to what's mandated.

Comment: @BenVoigt Sure but I would like to elide not only the space for the vtable, but also the space for the vtable pointer.  Incidentally, I wonder if there's a similar trick for checking the number of branches, other than looking at the disasm.

Comment: To adjust the class memory layout during optimization, the optimizer would have to prove that a pointer never escapes where external code can see it.  Which is a condition that's already not met, since you've passed exactly such a pointer to `printf`.

Comment: Wouldn't a final inheritence work here ?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the vfntable also contains the RTTI information.  (I believe Herb Sutter had a presentation where this overhead could be automagically deleted if not used.  I don't know of any compilers that have incorporated his suggested technique. Possibly requires a change to the C++ standard.)

Comment: @engf-010 I forgot to mention, I did use `final` in the descending class, both on the class itself and it in its method declarations.

Comment: @Eljay Good point.  Note that I'm also passing `-no-rtti` to clang.

Comment: @BenVoigt ah, I see now why adjusting layout is hard.  Thanks!  And, I bet the compiler/linker *is* smart enough to merge the useless branch, which is actually what's bothering me the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proving that (safely deriived) pointers to instances of your class are never passed to any code the compiler cannot examine is insanely hard.

Once such a pointer is in any code the compiler cannot examine, it must provide a vtable pointer to support RTTI and dynamic dispatch.  And this must be ABI compatible with someone else who inherits from your API and implements a different implementation.

You intend there to be exactly one implementation of this interface.  But you cannot communicate this to your compiler, so it does not know this.

An example of this is the fact you passed the pointer to `printf` above.  The implementation of `printf` is opaque to your C++ compiler (at some level of iteration); as far as your compiler knows, the value is cast back to the interface pointer and examined using RTTI.  Or passed to some function that consumes the abstract API you specified, and other code passes a different implementation.

Devirtualization, removal of virtual dispatch, and object elimination are things that C++ compilers do when optimizing code.  It is plausible such a set of operations could occur; amusingly, attempting to detect offsets of members is the kind of thing that would block these optimizations.

I can write code where created objects don't exist jn the output assembly, and vtable calls are skipped.  They aren't going to be fiddling with raw memory, however, because that kind of operation makes optimizers give up.

Comment: Thanks!  So, while the vtable memory footprint can't be eliminated, the redundant branching might actually be eliminated, that's good news!  I think the only way I could verify that would be to study the resulting machine code.

Comment: @prideout use `final` extensively.  There is a chance.